# Visual Studio 2015 RTM Find in Files dialog broken

Tags: visual-studio-2015

The `Find in Files` and `Replace in Files` dialogs will not open.  Neither through shortcuts nor through the menu items.

What could be the problem, how could I debug this?

**Update:**

The same dialogs are broken on my copy of Visual Studio 2013 as well.  This started happening after uninstalling VS2015 RC and installing VS2015 RTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually was able to figure this out.  It was one of my extensions (VS Settings Switcher) that caused the issue, disabling it solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Created an issue: https://github.com/RxDave/SettingsSwitcher/issues/1

Answer (score 16):

I thought i had this problem, but as it turns out, the dialog was not visible on my primary screen.

Using the find in files shortcut, typing some text and pressing enter did bring up the find results 1 panel.

The find in files dialog was open and undocked on my third screen which I don't actively use and had turned off. Visual studio 2015 enterprise had decided to put it there by it self.

After hitting **"Ctrl + Shift + F"**, the main window will blink. Then hit **"Win + Arrow left/right"** until the search dialog appears on screen.

Comment: Thanks VS Team, another 30 minutes of my time wasted.

Comment: Adds to the awesome list of "features nobody asked for" from Microsoft. Really, Microsoft, sort your stuff out.